# Add a trusted SSL Certificate to Javascript Request

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, xmlhttprequest

I am developing an WebApp, which is communicating with an HTTP-server. Of course I want to use an HTTPS connection instead of the HTTP. With this link [Jetty - How to configure SSL](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL) I was  able to create an certificate for my server with embedded Jetty.

Now I want to add the created certificate to my JavaScript client. How does it work?

At the moment my Javascript-Request looks like this: How can i add a certifcate?

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = localStorage.getItem("url") + "login";
var params = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        // server and request all right

    }
}
http.send(params);
```

The Server is **only** contacted by my WebApp, so there is no need to register my SSL Key on an official authority site. I only have to tell the Javascript function to trust my server.

Answer (score 3):

You can't programatically add a certificate to a browser at that level. A browser will either handle SSL certificates itself (globally, across the whole browser) or it will use the operating system's store for them.

Any instructions will be browser/OS specific. If you want to provide a service outside of a controlled environment (e.g. a company Intranet) then you will need to use a recognised authority service to make it feasible.